# Fulton Algebraic Curves, Exercise 2.5

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Exercise 2.5 says (in part): "Let $F$ be an irreducible polynomial in $k[X,Y]$ [$k$ algebraically closed], and suppose $F$ is monic in $Y$: $F = Y^n + a_1(X)Y^{n-1} + \cdots$, with $n>0$. Let $V=V(F)\subset\mathbb{A}^2$. Show that the natural homomorphism from $k[X]$ to $\Gamma(V) = k[X,Y]/(F)$ is one-to-one".

Surely this is not a sharp condition; for example, if $F=XY-1$, then $\Gamma(F) \cong k[X,1/X]$, and the natural homomorphism is one-to-one.

What is an example of an irreducible $F$ for which this statement does not hold? It seems to me that if some polynomial $g\in k[X]$ maps to zero in $\Gamma(V)$, then it must be a multiple of $F$, which never happens.

Comment: As you may have guessed, the reason for assuming $F$ is monic in $Y$ is the second part of the exercise: "show that the residues $1, \overline{Y}, \ldots, \overline{Y}^{n-1}$ generate $\Gamma(V)$ over $k[X]$ as a module." This is an example of "integral + finite type $\implies$ finite" as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/903375/).

Answer (score 3):

The condition of being one-to-one or injective is equivalent to the map being *dominant*, i.e., the closure of the image is the whole target variety (see Georges' answer in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407835/injective-map-on-coordinate-rings-implies-dense-image) for example). In the particular case we're dealing with you have the following composition of ring maps:
$$
k[x]\hookrightarrow k[x,y]\twoheadrightarrow k[x,y]/(f),
$$
which, in turn, geometrically corresponds to:
$$
V(f)\hookrightarrow\mathbb{A}_{x,y}^2\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{A}^1_x,
$$
where the first map is the embedding of the curve and the last map is the projection onto the $x$-coordinate.

With this in mind your question translates to asking for a curve $V(f)$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$ such that its projection map onto the $x$-axis is *not* dominant, this is, when is/isn't the closure of the image all of $\mathbb{A}^1_x$?  Now, since $\mathbb{A}^1$ has dimension 1 the closure of such a set can either be the whole space or a 0-dimensional subspace, this is, a finite union of closed points. Can you finish the argument from here?